# How to format my email php mailer

Tags: html, phpmailer, php

When I send the email with html tags.Gmail shows the tags also.Why is that? any solution?how to ad images bold text colored text according to my code?
here is my email content code

```
 smtpmailer("$email", 'website@yahoo.com', '<html><body>website.lk Password recovery', 'Password recovery','Dear "'.$name."\"\n\nUse your new password to login and reset your password as you wish.\nTo reset password go to your \"My Account\" page and click \"Change my password\"\n\n"."Here is your new password:\n\n"."Password: "."$password"."\n\nBack to get bump: www.website.lk\n\nRegards,\n website.lk Admin\n</body></html>");

$reset_msg="Recovery completed. Check your e-mail !";       
}else{
$reset_msg="Error in sending email.Try again !";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By including the below headers

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


    $headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Source,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

if you are using PHP Mailer,

```
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/image1.gif");      
$mail->AddAttachment("images/image2.gif");
```

Comment: @LahiruChathuranga you are probably using PHPMailer, this answer will not help you, this will only help if you use the simple `mail` function. Please checkout my answer if you are using PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this function:

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then change the line of `$mail->Body = $body;` to code blow:

```
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

This change will allow you to send HTML emails via PHPMailer, You can also add `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` to avoid future problems with special characters ...

Answer (score 0):

Use $mail->IsHTML(ture);
If on phpmailer..